# How to grep lines NOT starting with '##' without excluding lines starting with '#'

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file where some lines start with ## and others with #.

Some lines have neither of the above.

I'd like to return all lines EXCEPT those starting with ##.

Running `grep "^[^##]" myfile.ext` gets rid of both lines starting with ## and with #.

Kindly assist.

Example file input

> ## First line
>
> #  Second line
>
> Third line
>
> Fourth line

I would like to return

> #  Second line
>
> Third line
>
> Fourth line

Comment: The `[^...]` construct means "any single character except characters from the list after ^". Consequently, `[^##]` means "any character except #". As a result, all lines except those starting with # are printed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @berndbausch!

Comment: How to do this recursively for all nested files in a directory (ie. without specifying a filename)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -v "^##" filename
```

`-v` option removes lines containing the pattern.

Comment: Thanks @unxnut!